# Semi-classical limit of GC partition function

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In one of the problem sets for my course on statistical mechanics, there was a question asking us to consider the semi-classical limit of the partition function $\exp(-\mu / kT) \gg 1$. My question is why this constitutes a semi-classical limit.
The couple of ideas I had were:

1. the terms in the partition function sum $\mathcal{Z}= \exp(- \beta E_r + \beta \mu N_r)$ decay rapidly with increasing $N_r$ when we impose the above condition. This implies that energy states are essentially singly occupied or unoccupied. Thus quantum effect would not be prevalent.
2. My impression was that a classical limit involved high temperature (doesn't really make sense for the above condition)/ low particle density. Additionally, I had read that $\mu$ could be interpreted as a willingness of the system to receive new particles. A large negative chemical potential would imply a high willingness of the system to receive new particles.

Do any of these thoughts seem like valid explanations?